# cv2.bitwise_and sizes of input arrangements are not match error

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am taking this error *(-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match)*. How can I fix this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("foto2.png")
image2 = cv2.imread("foto3.png")

bitAnd = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image2)


cv2.imshow("FOTO1", image)
cv2.imshow("FOTO2", image2)
cv2.imshow("AND", bitAnd)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: check the `.shape` of each array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resize 2 images to the same size.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the shape of each of `image` and `image2`:

```py
print(image.shape)
print(image2.shape)
```

You can then be sure if the image do not have the same dimensions.
If they do not have the same dimensions, you can crop or resize one of them.

For example, to crop `image`:

```py
>>> cropped_image = image[O:500, 0:500]
>>> cropped_image.shape
(500,500)
```